# JQuery selector to ignore elements inside a specific class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a JQuery selector to select all `.widget` elements inside a editor but exclude widgets inside a nested editor. Its much more simple to explain by viewing the below HTML. As you can see I've labelled which elements I want to select and which I do not.

```
<div id='editor1' data-type='editor' class="widget">
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <div>
        <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    </div>

    <div id='embed-editor2' data-type='editor' class="widget"> <!-- This element should not be included in select qry -->
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
    </div>

    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
</div>
```

My selector can successfully select all widgets inside a specific editor AND ignore 'nested' editors BUT it does not ignore the 'nested' widgets. Ie, it will select widgets that are inside `#embed-editor2` when it should not.

```
$('#editor1 .widget:not([data-type="editor"])').activateWidget();
```

Any idea how I can achieve my objectives in JQuery? Preferably with a selector?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the embedded editor, if it exists, will be exactly one level down from the top, then you can use the descendant selector and `:not` to ensure that the first descendant is not a `[data-type='editor']`:

```
#editor1 > .widget:not([data-type="editor"]), #editor1 > *:not([data-type="editor"]) .widget
```

```css
#editor1 > .widget:not([data-type="editor"]),
#editor1 > *:not([data-type="editor"]) .widget {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='editor1' data-type='editor' class="widget">
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <div>
        <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    </div>

    <div id='embed-editor2' data-type='editor' class="widget"> <!-- This element should not be included in select qry -->
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
    </div>

    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
</div>
```

If the nested editor could be of arbitrary depth, selecting it with a single selector would still be possible, but a lot uglier, since you'd have to use `:not` on every child:

```
#editor1 > .widget:not([data-type="editor"]),
#editor1 > *:not([data-type="editor"]) > .widget:not([data-type="editor"]),
#editor1 > *:not([data-type="editor"]) > *:not([data-type="editor"]) > .widget:not([data-type="editor"])
// ...
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Even if you prefer plain selectors, it's a bad idea. Instead, it'd be better to filter the elements afterwards to check that their closest `[data-type="editor"]` is the one you want:

```
$('#editor1 .widget')
  .filter((_, elm) => elm.closest("[data-type='editor']").id === 'editor1')
```

```js
$('#editor1 .widget')
  .filter((_, elm) => elm.closest("[data-type='editor']").id === 'editor1')
  .css({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='editor1' data-type='editor' class="widget">
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <div>
        <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    </div>

    <div id='embed-editor2' data-type='editor' class="widget"> <!-- This element should not be included in select qry -->
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
        <p class="widget">Should NOT be in select qry</p>
    </div>

    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
    <p class="widget">Should be in select qry</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but the embeded editor isn't always going to be exactly one level down it could be N.

Comment: If it may be deeply nested, I don't think you should use a single selector - filter the collection instead